# Is getting transit visa for UK easier for Indians who already have a valid US visitor's visa

Tags: transit-visas

When traveling from BOM-ORD via LHR, is transit visa for UK a must for Indian citizens ?

If so, wouldn't getting a UK visa for an Indians who already has a valid US visitor's visa easier ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don’t need a visa to transit via LHR if travelling to/from the US with a valid visa. The [UK government’s “check if you need a visa” tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes) states, even in the case where you need to go through passport control:

> #### Transiting without a visa
>
> You may be eligible to transit without a visa if:
>
> - you arrive and depart by air
> - have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
> - have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)
>
> One of the following must also apply:
>
> - you’re travelling to (or on part of a reasonable journey to) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for that country
> - you’re travelling from (or on part of a reasonable journey from) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for that country
>   (…)